# What is the meaning about "xclip -sel"?

Tags: shell

what is the meaning of 'xclip -sel clip'?

I can't find the `'-sel'` in xclip API.

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Also read here as a complement: https://superuser.com/questions/200444/why-do-we-have-3-types-of-x-selections-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man xclip` is your friend: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip

TL;DR it tells you which X selection to copy the text to

Comment: Thanks, Now, I know that -selection can be abbreviated.